# Route does not redirect Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, controller, routes

I am trying to verify a new user using an email.

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails())
    {   
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    }   
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try 
    {   
        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        $email = new EmailVerification(new User(['email_token' => $user->email_token]));
        Mail::to($user->email)->send($email);
        DB::commit();
        $this->guard()->login($user);
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {   
        DB::rollback();
        return back();
    }   
}

public function verify($token)
{
    User::where('email_token',$token)->firstOrFail()->verified();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

**routes/web.php**

`Route::get('register/verify/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@verify');`

The issue I am having is that the path never gets triggered, even though the email has the correct link. If I remove `$this->guard()->login($user);` it does activate it, but it doesn't log in and I need it, so the user redirects to a specific page and stays there until the account is being verified.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: what happens? it redirects to somewhere or nothing happens?

Comment: did `verify()` method call?

Comment: @Wreigh Nothing happens when I go to the link in the email. Instead of going to the needed route `verify`, it just tried to log in without actually calling it.

Comment: @Ben That's the issue, `verify` is not being called even though I have the `route` in place.